# SVN and CVS downloadable windows client

Tags: svn, cmd, cvs

How can i use CVS and SVN commands in cmd line? Where can i download an appropriate CVS and SVN.exe?

```
svn commit <filename>     
svn log <filename>
```

I only found so far graphical user interfaces. 
(i know i need to setup the path variable)
(i use now tortoise, but i prefer command line commands)

Comment: No one uses CVS much anymore.  It's SVN or Git.

Comment: Ok, very helpful. I know, but i need now CVS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest CVS for Windows: http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/

See also: http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first one:
SVN client is:
http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download

SECOND (for CVS)?